# Encrypting parameters POST request with LoopJ

Tags: android, rest, loopj

I submitted an App to the Amazon App store, but it was rejected because of this issue:

> This app appears to be sending unencrypted, sensitive information. In this instance, the  E-MAIL and PASSWORD is being sent in clear text. Please update the app to encrypt all sensitive information.

I'm using [LoopJ](https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http) for my http requests and I'm not sure why my data is not being encrypted, or how to encrypt it.
Here's my code.

```
public class MYAuthClient {
  private static final String BASE_URL = "http://www.mywebservice.net/";

  private static AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

  public static void post(String url, RequestParams params, AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler) {
      client.post(getAbsoluteUrl(url), params, responseHandler);
  }

  private static String getAbsoluteUrl(String relativeUrl) {
      return BASE_URL + relativeUrl;
  }
}
```

To make requests. I do this.

```
RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    params.put("email", login_email);
    params.put("password", login_pass);
    MYAuthClient.post("api/v1/tokens.json", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
         @Override
         public void onStart() {
             // Initiated the request
         }

         @Override
         public void onSuccess(String response) {
            // Successfully got a response

         }

         @Override
         public void onFailure(Throwable e, String response) {
             // Response failed :(
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to connect to server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }

     });
```

Any help or a link to an example of using encryption along with LoopJ?
Thanks!

Comment: so where exactly do you think you're encrypting them? you're just putting them as parameters to a request, unless you encrypt them beforehand in your code they won't be encrypted; your code doesn't show encryption efforts. Consider hashing instead of encrypting.

Comment: That's what i'm asking. I'm not sure how to encrypt it. If someone could post an example that'd be helpful.

Comment: here's an example how to hash the password: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980658/how-to-sha1-hash-a-string-in-android

Comment: The email you'll probably have to obfuscate rather than encrypt since the key would be either predetermined or included with the data you post

Comment: It looks like Amazon are looking for that call to made over HTTPS and not HTTP like you are using.

Comment: try what @conor is suggesting, if it silences amazon's verification you're good. I'd still advise against storing passwords plain, encrypted or hashed without salt. Always salt and hash a password. To authenticate you can compare hashes instead of plaintexts

Comment: okay thanks! That seems like an easy solution. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution here is to provide a `https` endpoint for your webservice.

Then in your Android, change to endpoint to `https` like so:

```
http://www.mywebservice.net/
```

becomes

```
https://www.mywebservice.net/
```

You need to check that the server hosting the webservice is set up to server https. The solution to that problem is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I missed that. I'm 99% sure this should solve the issue with Amazon.