# best way to provide password in java ft. barteksc's pdfViewer

Tags: android, pdf, password-protection

I have set password in my pdf file. I want a best way to store its password in java. I did as the following but I think, it could be easily accessed by private hackers because it is stored as string.

```java
pdfView.fromAsset("eng1.pdf").scrollHandle(new DefaultScrollHandle(this)).password("eng@789").load();
```

Is there any better solution than to store as string value?
I went through many websites but didn't get the necessary solution.

Comment: why is not anyone helping me? :(

Comment: what would you like to have exactly ? Best way to have password encryption in android ?

Comment: @cantona_7 yes, because hard-coded string password can be easily accessed by the bad guys through java decompilers, i guess, so..

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41223937/how-can-i-encrypte-my-password-android-studio

Comment: @cantona_7  :(, this is relate to pdf's password store and that is another. it might be related for the pros but for the begineers like us, it is really tough to relate. :(