# Unable to export image to excel in Android

Tags: android, image, excel, apache-poi

I tried the following code to export image in excel on Android but I got an error. Copying logcat... please help!!

Code:

```
        package com.android.testexcel;

        import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
        import java.io.FileInputStream;
        import java.io.FileOutputStream;
        import java.io.IOException;

        import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFClientAnchor;
        import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFPatriarch;
        import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
        import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;

        public class MyWorkBook {
            void writeImageToExcel(String filePath, String imageFileName) {
                int col = 1, row = 1;
                HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
                HSSFSheet testsheet = wb.createSheet("test");
                System.out.println("The work book is created");
                try {
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
                    System.out.println("File sample.xls is created");
                    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(imageFileName);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream img_bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    int b;
                    while ((b = fis.read()) != -1)
                        img_bytes.write(b);
                    fis.close();
                    HSSFClientAnchor anchor = new HSSFClientAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0,
                            (short) col, row, (short) ++col, ++row);
                    int index = wb.addPicture(img_bytes.toByteArray(),
                            HSSFWorkbook.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG);
                    HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheet("test");
                    HSSFPatriarch patriarch = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
                    patriarch.createPicture(anchor, index);
                    anchor.setAnchorType(2);
                    wb.write(fos);
                    System.out.println("Writing data to the xls file");
                    fos.close();
                    System.out.println("File closed");
                } catch (IOException ioe) {

                    System.out
                            .println("Hi ! You got an exception. " + ioe.getMessage());
                    ioe.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }// end of class MyWorkBook
```

---

Logcat:

> 05-13 19:11:47.665: E/AndroidRuntime(7288): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   05-13 19:11:47.665: E/AndroidRuntime(7288): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils
>   05-13 19:11:47.665: E/AndroidRuntime(7288):     at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.addPicture(HSSFWorkbook.java:1580)
>   05-13 19:11:47.665: E/AndroidRuntime(7288):     at com.android.testexcel.MyWorkBook.writeImageToExcel(MyWorkBook.java:30)
>   05-13 19:11:47.665: E/AndroidRuntime(7288):     at com.android.testexcel.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:71)
>   05-13 19:11:47.665: E/AndroidRuntime(7288):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
>   05-13 19:11:47.665: E/AndroidRuntime(7288):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
>   05-13 19:11:47.665: E/AndroidRuntime(7288):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
>   05-13 19:11:47.665: E/AndroidRuntime(7288):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   05-13 19:11:47.665: E/AndroidRuntime(7288):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>   05-13 19:11:47.665: E/AndroidRuntime(7288):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
>   05-13 19:11:47.665: E/AndroidRuntime(7288):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   05-13 19:11:47.665: E/AndroidRuntime(7288):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>   05-13 19:11:47.665: E/AndroidRuntime(7288):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
>   05-13 19:11:47.665: E/AndroidRuntime(7288):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
>   05-13 19:11:47.665: E/AndroidRuntime(7288):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Thanks in Advance,
Hemant

Answer (score 0):

The crucial part of your error is this:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils
```

You need to make sure you include commons codec in your project. See the [Apache POI Components Page](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components) for the list of the dependencies of all the different bits of POI. (Or, if you use Maven, it'll handle that for you)

Comment: This problem is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9126567/method-not-found-using-digestutils-in-android

I am still not able to find the best way of editing the source files. Can ayone help me with this ?