# encodeHexString in android

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am performing some encryption using this

```
String encodedString = Hex.encodeHexString(s.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));
```

.
I have used commons-codec-1.8.jar in android.

Its displaying error

```
06-21 12:43:04.309: E/AndroidRuntime(1667): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex.encodeHexString
```

Please help.

Comment: Same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9126567/method-not-found-using-digestutils-in-android

Answer (score 2):

try

```
String encodedString = new String(Hex.encodeHex(s.getBytes("ISO-8859-1")));
```