# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex.encodeHexString

Tags: java, android, eclipse, kaltura

I am using Kaltura API in my android App.

I can use several API calls but each time I am trying to use a method includes in commons-codec-1.4.jar I get error and the App crashes.

This is my LogCat:

```
01-18 19:38:27.863: E/AndroidRuntime(21488): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-18 19:38:27.863: E/AndroidRuntime(21488): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex.encodeHexString
01-18 19:38:27.863: E/AndroidRuntime(21488):    at org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils.md5Hex(DigestUtils.java:226)
01-18 19:38:27.863: E/AndroidRuntime(21488):    at com.kaltura.client.KalturaClientBase.signature(KalturaClientBase.java:583)
01-18 19:38:27.863: E/AndroidRuntime(21488):    at com.kaltura.client.KalturaClientBase.extractParamsFromCallQueue(KalturaClientBase.java:491)
01-18 19:38:27.863: E/AndroidRuntime(21488):    at com.kaltura.client.KalturaClientBase.doQueue(KalturaClientBase.java:247)
01-18 19:38:27.863: E/AndroidRuntime(21488):    at com.kaltura.client.services.KalturaMediaService.add(KalturaMediaService.java:65)
01-18 19:38:27.863: E/AndroidRuntime(21488):    at adi.apps.wedding.MyProfile.onClick(MyProfile.java:120)
01-18 19:38:27.863: E/AndroidRuntime(21488):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
01-18 19:38:27.863: E/AndroidRuntime(21488):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
01-18 19:38:27.863: E/AndroidRuntime(21488):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
01-18 19:38:27.863: E/AndroidRuntime(21488):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-18 19:38:27.863: E/AndroidRuntime(21488):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-18 19:38:27.863: E/AndroidRuntime(21488):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
01-18 19:38:27.863: E/AndroidRuntime(21488):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-18 19:38:27.863: E/AndroidRuntime(21488):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-18 19:38:27.863: E/AndroidRuntime(21488):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
01-18 19:38:27.863: E/AndroidRuntime(21488):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-18 19:38:27.863: E/AndroidRuntime(21488):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I think that there is something wrong in my BuildPath but I cannot point anything specific.

I have the following Jar's:

```
commons-codec-1.4.jar
commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
(under the kalturaClient lib)

android-support-v4.jar
(under my App lib)
```

When debugging this, I can see that it fails in this method:

```
String md5 = DigestUtils.md5Hex(str);
```

And, I can see that the library does not have a source:

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils;
```

Note: This element neither has attached source nor attached Javadoc and hence no Javadoc could be found

Comment: Maybe this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9126567/method-not-found-using-digestutils-in-android

Comment: It could be related.The thing is that I cannot change anything in this library sine this is Kaltura's library (external API)

Comment: What if you put commons commons-codec-1.4.jar and commons-httpclient-3.1.jar directly in your lib folder? Or you can try to open the kaltura lib using jar xvf to see if the content is what you expect.

Comment: I have commons-codec-1.10.jar in libs folder, and still have this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you change the kaltura client?
You have the sources, so just make the necessary change

Answer (score 1):

Put `commons-codec-1.4.jar` in your App's lib. Obviously, it is required but not present.