# How to generate Android App fingerprint from code when app targets Android 28?

Tags: android, sha1

In order to check if the app is running on a non modified version of the APK I'm checking the app SHA1 signature at runtime.
This was working fine until now, but if I now want to target Android 28 it doesn't work anymore

```
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: The BC provider no longer provides an implementation for MessageDigest.SHA1.  Please see https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/03/cryptography-changes-in-android-p.html for more details.
```

Is there another way to do this from code?
I failed to find any solution until now...

Comment: Show your code plz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use sha-1 by code below. Note that "`SHA-1`", not the "`SHA1`"

```
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
```

Details: [Make SHA1 encryption on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757024/make-sha1-encryption-on-android)